# React Native - Defined State not able to be use

Tags: javascript, android, ecmascript-6, react-native

This Screen was navigate from other Screen. When this screen is open, it will go to load some data from Webhost database and fill them into the View Controls. There are few variable is defined in the Constructor(State), but when the program trying to call the `ShowAll()` function (click the Show Button) to display an Alert Message with the content of a defined variable in state, the program display this error.

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.RecipeName')

[image]

```
export default class SecondActivity extends Component
{


   static navigationOptions = { title: 'View Details',};


constructor(props) {
   super(props)
     this.state={
       RecipeID : '',
       RecipeName : '',
       RecipeType : '',
       RecipeIngredient : '',
       RecipeStep : ''
     }
}

componentDidMount(){

fetch('https://unsurfaced-cross.000webhostapp.com/getRecipeDetailRN.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({

      // Getting the id.
      RecipeID: this.props.navigation.state.params.ListViewClickItemHolder

    })

  }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

          this.setState({

            RecipeID : responseJson[0].RecipeID,
            RecipeName : responseJson[0].RecipeName,
            RecipeType : responseJson[0].RecipeType,
            RecipeIngredient : responseJson[0].RecipeIngredient,
            RecipeStep : responseJson[0].RecipeStep

          })

        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });

  }

  ShowAll(){
    Alert.alert(
     'Alert Title',
     this.state.RecipeName,  // **ERROR COME FROM THIS LINE**
     [
     {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
     {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
     {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
     ],
    { cancelable: false }
  )

}




render()
{

return(
   <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>

    <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'column'}} >

     <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} > {'Recipe ID = ' + this.state.RecipeID} </Text>

     <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} > {'Recipe Name = '} </Text>

     <TextInput
       style={styles.textInput}
       onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({RecipeName: text})}
       value={this.state.RecipeName}
     />

     <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} > {'Recipe Type = '} </Text>



     <Picker
       style={{width: 200}}
       selectedValue={this.state.RecipeType}
       onValueChange={
         (itemValue, itemIndex) => {
           this.setState({RecipeType: itemValue, isLoading:true})
           this.componentDidMount()
           this.forceUpdate()
         }
       }>

                             <Picker.Item label="Vegetarian" value="Vegetarian" />
                             <Picker.Item label="Fast Food" value="Fast Food" />
                             <Picker.Item label="Healthy" value="Healthy" />
                             <Picker.Item label="No-Cook" value="No-Cook" />
                             <Picker.Item label="Make Ahead" value="Make Ahead" />

       </Picker>


     <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} > {'Ingredient = '} </Text>

     <TextInput
       style={styles.textInput}
       onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({RecipeIngredient: text})}
       value={this.state.RecipeIngredient}
     />

     <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} > {'Step = '} </Text>

     <TextInput
       style={styles.textInput}
       onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({RecipeStep: text})}
       value={this.state.RecipeStep}
     />


     <Button
         title="Show"
         onPress={this.ShowAll}
         color="#841584"
     />

    </View>

  </View>
);
}
}
```

[image]

The RecipeName Variable was already defined in Consturctor(State), it also able to be used/called by the Views too. But when come to the `ShowAll()` function, it become Undefined.

Why/How is would become undefined when the Code is already there?

Comment: Did you try with onPress={this.ShowAll.bind(this)} ?

Comment: Yes, it's work, thank you.

Comment: But usually I called function like the code above and does not occur any problem, why should we add .bind(this) in this case? What is the different actually? @firats

Comment: If you use an ES6 class and you want to call your function in render, React no longer autobinds. One way to resolve this is to call bind in render. But this approach actually not good. Because the function is reallocated on every render. So, there are several ways to do it. I will explain in answers.

Comment: sure, please do.

Comment: and this is the source you can find more information about bindings and performance analysis. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Binding in Render**

```
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

If you use an ES6 class and you want to call your function in render, React no longer autobinds. One way to resolve this is to call bind in render. But this approach actually not good. Because the function is reallocated on every render. So, there are several ways to do it.

**Use Arrow Function in Render**

This approach is similar to binding in render approach. You can avoid changing the this context by using an arrow function in render:

```
onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
```

This is another approach to do the same thing but the performance still same with binding in render. Only difference is you are not using 'this'.

**Bind in Constructor**

One way to avoid binding in render is to bind in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

This is the approach currently recommended in the React docs for “better performance in your application”. You just bind once and use every time you press the button inside your render.